# How can I make this Java method completely generic

Tags: java, templates

I have a method which calculates the 95th percentile of an ArrayList of type Float containing statistics data:

```
    public String calculatePercentile(ArrayList<Float> arrayOfStats) {
    this.statistics = (ArrayList<Float>) arrayOfStats.clone();
    int N = statistics.size();
    int integerPart =0;
    int fractionalPart =0;
    int fraction =0;
    float rank =0;
    float floatPoint =0;
    float interpolate=0;
    float interpolateFirstPart =0;
    float interpolateSecondPart =0;

      if (N == 0) {
        return Float.toString(0);
       } else {   
         Collections.sort(statistics);
         rank = (float) ((P / 100.0) * (N - 1));
            if (rank == Math.round(rank)) {
              return Float.toString(statistics.get((int) rank));               
            } else {
                String split = Float.toString(rank);
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(floatRegExPattern);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(split); 
                while(matcher.find()) {
                integerPart = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
                fractionalPart = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
                }

                if (fractionalPart < 10) {
                    floatPoint = (float) (fractionalPart / 10);
                } else {
                    floatPoint = (float) fractionalPart / 100;
                }        
         fraction = integerPart + 1;
         interpolateFirstPart = statistics.get(fraction);
         interpolateSecondPart = statistics.get(integerPart);
         interpolate = interpolateFirstPart - interpolateSecondPart;
         return roundToTwoDecimalPlaces((floatPoint * interpolate) + interpolateFirstPart);
       }
      }
}
```

My question is how can I make this method generic so that it can not just accept and calculate ArrayLists of type Float, but it can also do Integers etc. I have tried to use templates such as

```
ArrayList<? as Number>
```

but when I get to Collections.sort, it complains and I couldn't figure out what was wrong. The return value needs to be a string.

Comment: It's pretty hard to use Number as a generic type as it has no way of doing arithmetic for obvious reasons. You could use List<Number> and then call doubleValue and do all the arithmetic in double precision however.

Comment: You better dont do that, your ArrayList already uses tripple the memory needed. So an ArrayList<Double> would be sufficient. If you want huge number of elements  consider using GrowingIntArray of Appache Commons-Math (the have statistic functions) ; Further using an Regex to calculate a 95% percentile is not recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
public <T extends Number> String calculatePercentile(ArrayList<T> arrayOfStats) {
```

and then use `Number.floatValue` to retrieve each stat as a `float`. You'll probably have to use this to write your own comparator to do the sorting. A comparator might look like this:

```
Comparator<Number> c = new Comparator<Number>() {
    public int compare(Number a, Number b) {
        return Float.compare(a.floatValue(), b.floatValue());
    }
}
```

Incidentally, a better way to assign to `statistics` would be:

```
this.statistics = new ArrayList<Number>(arrayOfStats);
```

You don't need to clone and cast.